# Observable Collection is coming null when implemented inside a custom trace listener inheriting from TraceListener

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have created a Custom Trace Listener inheriting from TraceListner class. Actually the idea is to use the Trace.Write method in the application which should update an Observable collection in a custom trace listener class which can be bound to a framework element.

Here is my Custom Trace Listener :

```
public class CustomTraceListener : TraceListener, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<TraceMessageInfo> _traceLogs;
    public ObservableCollection<TraceMessageInfo> TraceLogs
    {
        get
        {
            return _traceLogs;
        }
        set
        {
            _traceLogs = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TraceLogs");
        }
    }

    public CustomTraceListener()
    {
        if (TraceLogs == null)
        {
            TraceLogs = new ObservableCollection<TraceMessageInfo>();
            TraceLogs.Add(new TraceMessageInfo("Message", Enums.TraceCategory.Information.ToString()));
        }
    }

    public override void Write(object traceMessageInfo)
    {
        TraceLogs.Add(new TraceMessageInfo("New message", Enums.TraceCategory.Information.ToString()));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }   
}
```

Here is the xaml i am using to bind the observable collection to a ListBox (WPF).

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Name="TraceLogStackPanel">
                    <ListBox Name="lbTraceViewer" ItemsSource="{Binding TraceLogs, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Width="700" Background="{Binding Category,Converter={StaticResource TraceCategoryToColorConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Message, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
```

In the constructor i am setting the data context of the Stack Panel to this new Trace Listener.

```
this.TraceLogStackPanel.DataContext = new CustomTraceListener();
```

And finally on the click of execute button i am setting a dummy message to the write method of my custom trace listener.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        Trace.Write(new TraceMessageInfo("Message",Enums.TraceCategory.Error.ToString())); 
    }
```

In the configuration file i have set the custom trace listener and removed the default one.

My problem is that when i click on the execute there is no change in the collection. Sometimes when i try to debug it shows me the collection as null and sometimes it shows me the collection changed but no notifications to the UI. The listbox is showing only one message which i have set in the constructor of custom listener.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you tried switching `this.TraceLogStackPanel.DataContext = new CustomTraceListener();` to the `Loaded` event? so in the ctor where you have that code, just prepend the line with `Loaded += (sender, args) => `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you're creating an instance of the `CustomTraceListener`, your view is bound to a different instance than the .NET tracing system (it will create its own instance). I would change the collection to be a static instance, so you will see all messages:

```
private static readonly ObservableCollection<TraceMessageInfo> _traceLogs;
public ObservableCollection<TraceMessageInfo> TraceLogs
{
    get
    {
        return _traceLogs;
    }
}

static CustomTraceListener()
{
    _traceLogs = new ObservableCollection<TraceMessageInfo>();
    _traceLogs.Add(new TraceMessageInfo("Message", Enums.TraceCategory.Information.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: It's working and i understand that making the collection static would create only one instance which will be used by .net Trace class. Correct?

Comment: Well, you will still have 2 instances of `CustomTraceListener`. But since the collection is static, they both access the same collection.